# Vertx list of Rest API call in loop

Tags: java, rest, kotlin, vert.x

I'm new to vertx and Java environment. Below code calls a list of rest API endpoints and store the results in MongoDB and it works, but I'm not sure is this the right way to do it in vertx environment. Also, is there any improvements needs to be done?

```
     val deviceRepository = listOf("10.2.0.106",
                "10.2.0.120",
                "10.2.0.115",
                "10.2.0.112",
                "10.2.0.118",
                "10.2.0.119")

        internal class DeviceListVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {
            @OptIn(UnstableDefault::class)
            @ImplicitReflectionSerializer
            override fun start() {
        // mongo client connection
                val config = mapOf(Pair("db_name", "deviceList"), Pair("connection_string", "mongodb://localhost:27017"))
                val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient.create(vertx, JsonObject(config))

                val httpClient = WebClient.create(vertx)
       // loop through each IP address in deviceRepository and call rest end point http://{IP}/information/device
                deviceRepository.forEach { deviceIP ->
                    val request: HttpRequest<Buffer> = httpClient.get(deviceIP, "information/device")
                    request.send { ar ->
                        if (ar.succeeded()) {
                            // Obtain response
                            val response = ar.result()
                            mongoClient.save("devices", response.bodyAsJsonObject()) { res ->
                                if (res.succeeded()) {
                                    val id: String = res.result()
                                    println("Saved device with id $id")
                                } else {
                                    res.cause().printStackTrace()
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            println("Something went wrong " + ar.cause().message)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun stop() {
                println("DeviceListVerticle stopped")
            }
        }

        fun main() {
            val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
            vertx.deployVerticle(DeviceListVerticle())
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a one-time task, I think using `WebClient` without `Verticle` would be better.  I think verticles are well-suited to encapsulate reactive computation (e.g., serving requests, periodic execution) into concurrency- and deployment-friendly bundles.